# Reading headers from fits files in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read headers from specific fits files in a directory.  I don't want to obtain the headers from every file, just those that I specify.  Here is the code that I have thus far:

```
import os
from astropy.io import fits as pyfits

def mycode(files):

    fits = []
    headers = []
    for i in files:
        fits.append(i)

        for j in fits:
            if 'rf' in j:
                hdulist = pyfits.open(j)
                header = hdulist[0].header['headername']
                headers.append(header)

    return headers

pathway = 'the directory'
dirs = os.listdir(pathway)

print mycode(dirs)
```

However, when I run that, it says "No such file or directory" and gives the name of one of the files I was trying to access.  I would appreciate any help!

Comment: I am pretty sure you may wish to reduce 'for i in files' and 'j in fits' to just "for j in files:", as your second for loop will execute over the same items multiple times before fits is properly filled.

Comment: You may wish to also include more information such as the error log so that we can see what line is actually failing, because maybe you aren't passing a proper directory, or using the imported libraries properly?

Answer (score 0):

When you use **pyfits.open(j)**, python understands that the file is in the current directory (the one where this script is). So since you get the names of the files from another directory, python doesn`t find them. One solution would be to attach the directory to the beginning of every file.